Component identification: 16C 2CNUC diode (probably) LittelFuse
This diode is found in set of inputs, between signal and earthing.
I can recognise LF logo as LittelFuse, and unable to find the rest, 16C 2CNUC.

What it could be?
EDIT
As suggested, measured and can confirm this is SMA size: 2.7mm wide, 4.27mm long and 2.25mm high.


Could they be the item listed with the marking "16C" in this datasheet?

There are SMA, SMB and SMC diodes with a "16C" marking made by Littlefuse. That's why dimensions are important for identification questions.

Sure, I will add dimensions as soon as I got my hands on it. Most likely monday

It is a P4SMA16CA bi-directional diode.
Package SMA to be confirmed with a calliper as mentionned above in the comments.
Picture from lcsc:

